# jq copy fields from multiple source fields down to one field

Tags: jq

I tried to find an answer but didn't unfortunately find a good answer.
I am having following json source that I am trying to normalize into one specific field for all values that contain `true` or `false`.
At the same time there is a special key `e` that I want to copy over to specific keys.

That's the json:

```
{
  "an": {
    "e": false
  },
  "at": {
    "c": {
      "e": false
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "s": true
  },
  "e": {
    "d": true,
    "e": true,
    "f": true,
    "n": true,
    "p": true,
    "r": true,
    "s": true
  },
  "l": {
    "f": "info"
  },
  "m": {
    "b": true
  },
  "ma": {
    "mo": "pov",
    "s": true
  },
  "r": {
    "mo": "pov",
    "s": true
  }
}
```

That's the output I am aiming for. The `val` key should be basically in the second hierarchy at the same place. The keys and values have been basically anonymized.

```
{
  "an": {
    "e": false,
    "val": false
  },
  "at": {
    "c": {
      "e": false
    },
    "val": false
  },
  "b": {
    "s": true,
    "val": true
  },
  "e": {
    "d": true,
    "e": true,
    "f": true,
    "n": true,
    "p": true,
    "r": true,
    "s": true
  },
  "ed": {
    "val": true
  },
  "ee":{
    "val": true
  },
  "ef": {
    "val": true
  },
  "en": {
    "val": true
  },
  "ep": {
    "val": true
  },
  "er": {
    "val": true
  },
  "es": {
    "val": true
  },
  "l": {
    "f": "info"
  },
  "m": {
    "b": true,
    "val": true
  },
  "ma": {
    "mo": "pov",
    "s": true,
    "val": true
  },
  "r": {
    "mo": "pov",
    "s": true,
    "val": true
  }
}
```

I basically wanted to collect these fields all into a val field on the same place.
Maybe this breakdown would help to make that more clear

```
  "an": {
    "e": false
  },
```

to

```
  "an": {
    "e": false,
    "val": false

  },
```

should be copied the field value from `an.e` to `an.val`:

```
  "an": {
    "e": false
  },
```

Same for keys 
`at.c.e` to `at.val`
`b.s` to `b.val`
`m.b` to `m.val`
`ma.s` to `ma.val`
`r.s` to `r.val`
key `f` doesn't contain a subfield contaning `true` or `false`
key `e` has the issue the it contains multiple subfields with `true`
 or `false`
That's why following copy scheme basically merged main and subkey together:
`e.d` to `ed.val`
`e.e` to `ee.val`
`e.f` to `ef.val`
`e.n` to `en.val`
`e.p` to `ep.val`
`e.r` to `er.val`
`e.s` to `es.val`
Hope that helps for clarification.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you want to add `val=true` to every top level key? Where does `ed`/`ef`/etc. come from? Why does key `e` not contain `val`?

Comment: Can you shorten your example? Can you use more descriptive names for the keys? It's really hard to follow/understand tens of single-letter keys.

Comment: Added clarifying notes to initial request and corrected a typo.

Comment: I am still unable to follow your rules. Why does `e.d` become `ed.val`, but `at.c.e` becomes `at.val` (I'd expect `atce.val` to match the other rule)

Comment: Because the val field should be always in second object field like `<key>.val`. That would not be possible for `e` keys like `e.d` down to `ed`. That was at least the idea. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Does anyone probably have an idea what could be done here?